# Show/Hide Progress bar based on true/false variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple progress bar like so:

```
<div class="progress" ng-show="logging" id="login-progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
       Logging In...
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice I have an `ng-show="logging"` on the very first div. I am wanting to make this show/hide based on a true/false variable.

```
$scope.logging = false;

    authen.pass = function() {

        $scope.logging = true;

        $timeout(function(){

            ref.authWithPassword({
                email    : authen.email,
                password : authen.password
            }, function(error, authData) {
                if (error) {
                    $scope.logging = false; // This isn't working
                    swal({
                        title: "Whoops!",   
                        text: error,
                        timer: 4000,   
                        showConfirmButton: false
                    });
                } else {
                    $window.location.href = '#/dashboard';
                }
            });

        }, 2000);
    }
```

Above is my controller code that sets the logging variable to false by default. Once the function is called, it becomes true. If there is an error it should be set to false. This doesn't seem to be happening.

Everything I've found online says that is exactly how you do it. What is wrong with this code?

I've tried taking it out of the $timeout function and that still didn't make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the callback of `authWithPassword` is executed outside of an angular digest cycle. It should work like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.logging = false });
```

Maybe this article helps to understand it: [Understanding Angular’s $apply() and $digest()](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)